# Problem installing Nvidia Geforce 310m drivers

Tags: 11.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed ubuntu 11.04.

I can not install my nvidia Geforce 310m driver. I active it by Hardware Drivers (recomended) but it is not in use. I ran this command in terminal `sudo nvidia-xconfig` then restarted my computer.

My computer after restarting can not load login window and it is black. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i about to report this. Thanks. exact same issue in dell vostro 3300

Comment: Yes. For recovery issues, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same problem I had with 10.04. Check out my blog on how to solve this:

http://www.sanafapech.net/2011/04/geforce-310m-330m-400m-etc-con-linux.html

(or translated by Google)

http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=es&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sanafapech.net%2F2011%2F04%2Fgeforce-310m-330m-400m-etc-con-linux.html

Cheers.

Comment: this is for 10.10. can you update it for 11.10?